# json normalize to Dataframe for nested objects, Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i am trying to use normalize function to convert json to data frame using json_normalize.
This is the json i am working with

```
data = {
    "Parent":
[
        {
        "Attributes":
        [
            {
                "Values": [{
                    "Month": "Jan",
                    "Value": "100"
                }],
                "Id": "90",
                "CustId": "3"
            },
            {
                "Values": [{
                    "Month": "Jan",
                    "Value": "101"
                }],
                "Id": "88" 
            },
            {
                "Values": [{
                    "Month": "Jan",
                    "Value": "102"
                }],
                "Id": "89" 
            }
        ],
        "DId": "1234"
    },
    {
        "Attributes":
        [
            {
                "Values": [{
                    "Month": "Jan",
                    "Value": "200"
                }],
                "Id": "90",
                "CustId": "3"
            },
            {
                "Values": [{
                    "Month": "Jan",
                    "Value": "201"
                }],
                "Id": "88" 
            },
            {
                "Values": [{
                    "Month": "Jan",
                    "Value": "202"
                }],
                "Id": "89" 
            }
        ],
        "DId": "5678"
    }
]
}
```

and this is what i have tried

```
print(type(data))
result = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['Parent',['Attributes']], max_level=2)
print(result.to_string())
```

And it gave the result , but it is missing the DId and values column is still a list of dict
[image]

And this is what i want to achieve

[image]

Any guidance how to accomplish it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is one way of achieving this, I think step1 and step2 can be combined together which needs some more insight on `pd.json_normalize`

```
#step1
df1=pd.json_normalize(
    data['Parent'],["Attributes","Values"]
)
#step2
df2=pd.json_normalize(
    data['Parent'],"Attributes","DId",
)
df2=df2.drop(['Values'], axis=1)

result=df2.join(df1).reindex(['DId','Id','CustId','Month','Value'], axis=1)\
.sort_values(by=['DId','Id']) \
.rename(columns={'Id':'Attr.Id','CustId':'Attr.CustId','Month':'Attr.Values.Month',
                'Value':'Attr.Values.value'
                })
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can specify meta data (data *above* the `record_path`) via the `meta` keyword argument (in combination with `errors='ignore'` for meta data that isn't necessarily there, like `CustId`). For instance

```py
result = pd.json_normalize(
    data,
    record_path=['Parent', 'Attributes', 'Values'],
    meta=[
        ['Parent', 'DId'],
        ['Parent', 'Attributes', 'Id'],
        ['Parent', 'Attributes', 'CustId']
    ],
    errors='ignore'
)
```

results in

```
  Month Value Parent.DId Parent.Attributes.Id Parent.Attributes.CustId
0   Jan   100       1234                   90                        3
1   Jan   101       1234                   88                      NaN
2   Jan   102       1234                   89                      NaN
3   Jan   200       5678                   90                        3
4   Jan   201       5678                   88                      NaN
5   Jan   202       5678                   89                      NaN
```